# Clang Format is removing all the indent spaces on my empty lines

Tags: xcode, clang-format

I'm running `_clang-format` file using the `BBUncrustifyPlugin` for Xcode.

In Xcode, whenever I make a newline, it preserves the indentation spaces. (Spaces shown as •) Like so:

```
if(YES) { 
••••NSInteger myNum = 2;
••••
••••myNum = 4;
}
```

When I run my `_clang-format` file it removes the spaces from my code so now it looks like this:

```
if(YES) { 
••••NSInteger myNum = 2;

••••myNum = 4;
}
```

Not a huge deal, but it does make for annoying commit changes where every newline removes spaces. Not to mention if I go back to edit the file, I would prefer those spaces to already be there.

I can't seem to find a `_clang-format` key that can help me fix this. Any help?

Here's my current `_clang-format` file

```
BasedOnStyle: Chromium,
AlignTrailingComments: true,
BreakBeforeBraces: Linux,
ColumnLimit: 140,
IndentWidth: 4,
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false,
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4,
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true,
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true,
PointerBindsToType: false,
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1,
TabWidth: 8,
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2,
UseTab: Never,
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is an option to disable the removal of trailing spaces. However, clang-format does not appear to have that [option](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html). You can, however, set an option in Xcode to automatically remove trailing whitespace. (It's in the Xcode preferences; unfortunately, I'm not on a Mac right now, so I can't get a screenshot for you.)

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't address your clang-format question, it might still solve your problem. You can make Xcode trim whitespaces by checking both options below in `Preferences` > `Text Editing`:

```
While Editing:   ☑ Automatically trim trailing spaces  
                   ☑ Including whitespace-only lines
```